# Creating Git branch from another branch or from master?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, git-merge

So I am new to Git. I recently pulled a fresh version of the master branch from the repo.

I created a `branch(1)` for a feature and pushed it to the repo and created up a pull request. Now I created a new `branch(2)` with another feature, but since my pull request hasn't merged yet, pulling master again won't have that feature that I created in `branch1`.

Only when I create a new branch from `branch1` I get that feature. Before, I've been created new branches from the previous branches so I haven't had this issue, but I've been told that although it isn't a big deal, they want me to create new branch from the master instead.

What would git command would I have to do? Git merge on my local master?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to do this.

If you just want to create and check out a new branch from `master` without checking it out, you can do `git checkout -b new-branch master`.  If, instead, you'd prefer not to check it out, but just create it, you can run `git branch new-branch master`.

If you are already on `master`, perhaps since you're pulling in new changes from the remote, then you can use `git checkout -b new-branch` or `git branch new-branch`, depending on whether you want to check it out immediately or not.

When I'm creating new branches, I usually go to the main branch, run `git pull --ff-only origin main` to update my main branch, and then use `git checkout -b new-branch` to create and check out my new branch so I can work on it.  If you're not sure what to do, I recommend that approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would start *all branches* from the same branch (root branch, in your case the `master` branch). So if `branch1` is in a pull request, you start with `branch2` from the `master` branch. If the pull request from `branch1` is good (approved) and has been merged into the `master` branch, you can merge the `master` branch into your `branch2` so that you then have the *latest data* from the `master` branch in the current `branch2`.

But if the work in `branch2` is *based on the changes* where are in `branch1`, `branch2` must be based on `branch1`, and then `branch2` can also be started from `branch1`. If `branch1` is merged in `master`, the *source branch* of `branch2` is `master` then `branch1` was merged in `master`.

Look at this stackoverflow-[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339550/merging-two-separate-feature-branches-into-the-same-main-branch).